# Finding ranges in runs of numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying to find runs of years in a data frame (ideally using plyr)

I'd like to get from this:

```
require(plyr)

dat<-data.frame(
  name=c(rep("A", 11), rep("B", 11)),
  year=c(2000:2010, 2000:2005, 2007:2011)
  )
```

To this:

```
out<-data.frame(
  name=c("A", "B", "B"),
  range=c("2000-2010", "2000-2005", "2007-2011"))
```

It's easy enough to identify whether each group has a continuous run of years:

```
ddply(dat, .(name), summarise,
      continuous=(max(year)-min(year))+1==length(year))
```

How do I go about breaking down group "B" into two ranges?

Any ideas or strategies would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether you use a function from "plyr" or from base R, you need to first establish some groups. One way to detect the change in groups since your years are sequential is to look for where `diff` is not equal to 1. `diff` creates a vector of length one less than the input vector, so we'll initialize that with "1" and take the `cumsum` of the result.

Putting that mouthful of an explanation into practice, you can try something like this:

```
dat$id2 <- cumsum(c(1, diff(dat$year) != 1))
```

From here, you can use `aggregate` or your favorite grouping function to get the output you're looking for.

```
aggregate(year ~ name + id2, dat, function(x) paste(min(x), max(x), sep = "-"))
#   name id2      year
# 1    A   1 2000-2010
# 2    B   2 2000-2005
# 3    B   3 2007-2011
```

To use `range` with `aggregate`, you need to change `sep` to `collapse`, as below:

```
aggregate(year ~ name + id2, dat, function(x) paste(range(x), collapse = "-"))
```

Comment: Awesome - I'd never have thought of that.  For plyr I can finish it with ddply(dat, .(name, id2), summarise, paste(min(year), ":", max(year), sep="")).

Comment: @EdG or `ddply( dat , "id2" , summarise , Range = paste( range(year) ,collapse=" - ") )`

Answer (score 2):

Tooting my own horn,  `cgwtools::seqle` can be used to identify the splits. Run a loop or `*apply` over the `names` elements, and for each case,

```
foo <- seqle(dat$year, incr=1)
```

Then `length(foo$lengths)` will give you the number of groups, and the range of years is easily reconstructed from `foo$values` .

```
yeargroups <-  sapply(length(foo$lengths), function(x) c(foo$values[x],(foo$values[x]+foo$lengths[x]-1)))
```

Just proposing this in case someone has a similar situation with different parameters or desired subdivisions.

Comment: +1. I was going to mention it, but I thought I would give you a chance to show off your package :)